# How do you improve smithing really well without using the 'iron dagger' technique?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want Daedric armour really quick.

I am playing on the PS3.

Answer (score 0):

The method I used to use was a bit of a combination of skills.

In terms of Smithing, the one thing I found to be the most efficient in raising your skill level was making jewellery - particularly gold rings.

Now - before you ask "where am I going to get that much gold?" - here's the second part of my method. The [Transmute Mineral Ore](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Transmute_Mineral_Ore) spell can be found near Whiterun in a bandit camp called [Halted Stream Camp](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Halted_Stream_Camp). This is an upper level pell, so you may need to do a little bit of levelling before you can use it effectively. However, the other thing that mine is good for, is iron.

So, using your new transmutation spell, and an abundant resource of iron, you can alter your iron to silver, then gold (boosting your Alteration skill), then craft gold rings, (boosting your Smithing skill), and get you a fair bit of money when you sell them all (as well as a bit of levelling in your Bartering skill).

Comment: A good tactic, although at low levels, it's probably better to focus on leather bracers instead, since you get a practically unlimited supply of animal pelts. Five wolf pelts equals two tempered leather bracers, with one pelt being used for leather strips. Churn those out until you are high enough level to deal with the Halted Stream bandits or get silver and gold some other way.

Comment: @JohnLaviolette, If you have another suggestion, feel free to add it as another answer.